# Why a is undefined while b is 3 in var a=b=3?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I expected both `a` and `b` to be `3`. However, `a` is `undefined` and `b` is `3`. Why?

```
(function(){
    var a = b = 3;
})();

console.log(typeof a);//"undefined"
console.log(b);//3
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to behave that way on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgskkut9/)

Comment: It works, i have checked it in chrome at both head and body.

Comment: @HoboSapiens: That is because you didn't put the relevant code into your fiddle... Try http://jsfiddle.net/cgskkut9/1/

Comment: @chris The question has been updated to clarify the issue since I posted that fiddle.

Comment: —1: A mighty strange assumption given that `var` declares a local variable.

Comment: @HoboSapiens: Ah, apologies. I hadn't noticed. Still, probably worth leaving my comment there with the updated fiddle in it.

Comment: anonymous function with lexical scope enclosed prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as polluting the global scope. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The issue here is that most developers understand the statement `var a = b = 3;` to be shorthand for:

```
var b = 3;
var a = b;
```

But in fact, var a = b = 3; is actually shorthand for:

```
b = 3;
var a = b;
```

Therefore, b ends up being a global variable (since it is not preceded by the var keyword) and is still in scope even outside of the enclosing function.

The reason a is undefined is that a is a local variable to that self-executing anonymous function

```
(function(){
    var a = b = 3;
})();
```

Comment: You're right. I deleted the notes regarding use strict.

Answer (score 12):

```
var a=b=3
```

Is the same as:

```
var a = (b = 3)
```

And `var` statement applies only to `a`, and not to `b`. You can check the syntax of `var` statement [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2).

Therefore `a` will be defined in local scope and `b` will be defined in global scope. Inside function both `a` and `b` are 3 but after function returns registered local variable (`a`) is deleted. Since `b` is defined in global scope it is not deleted.

Answer (score 5):

`a` IS 3 indeed, but it's within the scope of the anounymous fucntion.

this line `var a = b = 3` is actually:

1. `b = 3`, whereas `b` is declared as a global variable.
2. return value of the assignment express `b=3` is, yes, the assigned value `3`.
3. `var a = the return value of previous expression`, thus equals `var a = 3`, but this time `a` is a local variable.

Outside the anounymous function, `b` is accessible, but `a` doesn't even exist, due to not defined in **global scope**.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote in the following style:

```
console.log(typeof b);//"number"
console.log(a);// error with a is not defined
```

So in case of yours `a` is unrecognized as it is not in global scope. BUT `b` is treated as global. `var` is used to declare a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the code below

```
'use strict'
(function(){
    var a = b = 3; // ERROR. Prevents global variable name clash
})();
```

And

```
(function(){
    var a = b = 3; // Silently assigns 3 to a global variable b
})();

console.log(typeof a);//"undefined"
console.log(b);// 3
```

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of **hoisting** as var a = b = 3; is actually shorthand for:

```
b = 3;
var a = b;
```

> here "a" is hoisted but "b" is not hoisted.

```
(function(){
   console.log(a) // undefined
   console.log(b) // ReferenceError: b is not defined
   var a = b = 3;
 })();
```

The reason is variables are hoisted when declared with var.